# How to share COM ports from hyper-V

Tags: serial-port, hyper-v, arduino

I am trying to enable COM ports from my host machine.

I have an Ubuntu 14.10 running on Hyper-V. Host machine is a Windows 8.1

[image]

How should I use these pipes?

The idea is to connect my Arduino, so I can use it through Hyper-V.

I was reading about socat, but I don't get the point.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm almost 5 years too late, but maybe this will help someone else.  Hyper-V provides data from a named pipe into the VM as a COM port, as you show above.  Hyper-V, rather unhelpfully, does not connect that named pipe to the host's COM port, which is what you would need to pass the data through to your VM.

I just wrote a Windows program that runs on the host OS and provides a link between the host COM port and the named pipe, allowing you to use the host COM port from your Ubuntu VM.

You need to run this as an admin user.

https://github.com/tdhoward/COMpipe